¿Como comparo una lista de tuplas con un string en haskell?
Tengo el siguiente problema: en un ejercicio me dan como entrada una lista de ternas y un string, necesito saber si el string es igual a lo que me va a devolver la lista de tuplas, el problema es que no puedo llamar a elem porque mi lista no es una lista cualquiera de la que pueda "sacar" cosas facilmente y realmente no se me ocurre como crear una funcion auxiliar que me "reduzca" mi lista de terna de cosas a una sola cosa que debe aparecer en todas las ternas. No se como ir del mi bool a algo comparable con un string, ideas?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
